# Erasing cache from all apps on phone via adb-shell command `fastboot erase cache`

Tags: android, fastboot

I'm trying to erase all app-caches via the official adb-shell from the SDK-Toolkit without having to root my phone. Does the command

`fastboot erase cache`

only deletes app-caches or does it remove app data and general data on the mobile harddrive too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the info on **fastboot** [tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/fastboot/info).

**Fastboot erase cache** should just erase the cache partition (check the output from that command).

To delete the app data there is another command:

```
fastboot erase data
```

But be careful with the commands you use. You could end up with unwanted results. Cheers.

Comment: Thank you for the link. Erasing the whole cache partition is not the same as deleting only the app-cache, right? Assume, that I only want to delete app-caches but not erasing the whole partition. How would I do that?

Comment: In this case it is the same. It will wipe out all the apps caches. This link can also help you: https://techbeasts.com/useful-adb-and-fastboot-commands-and-how-to-them/

Comment: @Doesbaddel If that fixed your issue, please mark this answer has it correct one so it can helper others :)